# Short url for Google News and Google Videos

Tags: google-search, url-shortening

On some occasions you want to provide some particular Google Search. You could simply copy the link from your browser's address bar, which often gives a very long link containing a lot of redundant stuff, see, for example, [this question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/27772/anonymize-a-google-search-url/) (and also [here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/47281/is-there-a-quick-way-of-getting-a-beautiful-url-to-a-google-search-query) and [here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/39818/how-should-i-write-the-url-for-a-specific-google-search-query)).

But you can also create a shorter link, if you remove from the url the things, which are not needed. For example `http://www.google.com/search?q=test&tbm=isch` is a link to Google Images search, the part `tbm=isch` means that it is search in images.

For many of services, you can get a nicer and shorter url:

- Google: `http://www.google.com/search?q=test` http://www.google.com/search?q=test
- Google Images: `http://images.google.com/images?q=test` http://images.google.com/images?q=test
- Google Books: `http://books.google.com/books?q=test` http://books.google.com/books?q=test
- Google Scholar: `http://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=test` http://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=test

But I did not find similar type of link for Google Videos. The link `http://video.google.com/video?q=test` http://video.google.com/video?q=test does not work (although http://video.google.com is a valid link).

I did not find this for Google News, either. The link http://news.google.com/news?q=test returns different results than http://www.google.com/search?q=test&tbm=nws.

> Are there such "short" URLs for Google Videos and Google News searches?

Comment: Loved your findings! Two notes, though: there's no need for the subdomain. So those work: [`google.com/search?q=test`](http://google.com/search?q=test) or [`google.com/images?q=test`](http://google.com/images?q=test). And `https` don't work.

Comment: @cregox: Google is all https all the time now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of October 2023,

1. http://news.google.com/news?q=test redirects to https://news.google.com/search?q=test (`search` instead of `news`)
2. Google Video, https://video.google.com/, was retired. For details, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Video.

---

As far as I knew, back in 2015, there wasn't a shorter URL for searching Videos and News. Instead, use the `tbm` parameter and the corresponding keyword:

- `vid` for videos -> https://www.google.com/search?tbm=vid&q=test
- `nws` for news -> https://www.google.com/search?tbm=nws&q=test

Bonus:

- `bks` for books -> https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=test
- <s>`app` for apps -> https://www.google.com/search?tbm=app&q=test</s>

For Maps, there is a "short" search URL -> https://www.google.com/maps?q=test

Related

- [Why does Google News not include my search?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/33689/88163)